# Break down this list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I was wondering if there is a good pythonic way to break down this list:

```
['1,2,3', '22', '33']
```

into the list:

```
['1','2','3','22','33']
```

using list comprehension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a list comprehension, it would look like this:

```
>>> L = ['1,2,3', '22', '33']
>>> [x for s in L for x in s.split(",")]
['1', '2', '3', '22', '33']
```

Comment: Actually I like this better than mine! Not sure how I forgot about this solution.

Comment: nested list comprehension works fine for this simple example, but they don't generalise as well as chain for more general cases (e.g. with sub-nesting)

Comment: +1 This is a very reasonable use of a nested for-loop in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

Since there were two answers already posted using the `sum()` function as a solution, I thought I would contribute one more way, using itertools.chain

```
from itertools import chain
x = ['1,2,3', '22', '33']
result = chain.from_iterable(i.split(',') for i in x)

print result
#<itertools.chain object at 0x1004b5e10>
```

The result of the chain command is a generator. So you could loop over the result, or cast it to another sequence type (tuple, list, set, ...)

Comment: You could also use `chain.from_iterable()` instead of `chain(*...)`. More explicit and stuff...

Comment: @stranac, in fact, it's not just a matter of explicitness; the `*` operator converts the generator into a tuple, defeating the point of using one.

Comment: @jdi This answer would be better if only the from_iterable approach were shown.  The star-unpacking happens on the stack, so it doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use `sum`, since it does repeated concatenation and creates a lot of copies. I would do this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l =  ['1,2,3', '22', '33']
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(s.split(',') for s in l))
['1', '2', '3', '22', '33']
```

It's true that it's slightly slower for very short lists:

```
>>> %timeit sum((s.split(',') for s in l), [])
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.38 us per loop
>>> %timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(s.split(',') for s in l))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.51 us per loop
```

But for long lists, it's *way* faster than using `sum`:

```
>>> l =  ['1,2,3', '22', '33'] * 500
>>> %timeit sum((s.split(',') for s in l), [])
100 loops, best of 3: 6.22 ms per loop
>>> %timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(s.split(',') for s in l))
1000 loops, best of 3: 664 us per loop
```

Actually, though, I rather like [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9559846/577088)'s answer. And a quick test shows that it's the fastest in all cases, to boot:

```
>>> l =  ['1,2,3', '22', '33'] 
>>> %timeit [x for s in l for x in s.split()]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 us per loop
>>> l =  ['1,2,3', '22', '33'] * 500
>>> %timeit [x for s in l for x in s.split()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 559 us per loop
```

Comment: I think the biggest advantage of the `chain.from_iterable` solution isn't the speed, but that it's much more straight forward than sum in my opinion..

Comment: @Voo, yes, I agree! But one of the things I love about Python is that, so often, when I do a test like the above, I find that the more straightforward option is also the more efficient option.

Comment: That's a great way to define python actually! I never formulated it that way myself, but now that you're saying it - yes, absolutely. Comparing python to say c++ makes that difference really obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Break down your problem. You can never see how to solve the whole problem at once, and Python never has simple built in solutions to whole problems. Figure out what the most basic pieces of your problem are, and there are often simple direct solutions to each piece. Then combine the solutions. Also, don't expect that you can wave a magic catch phrase like "list comprehension" at the problem to make it go away. Figure out what your solution needs to do, then think about whether a list comprehension can do that.

You have a string '1,2,3'. You need to split that into a list of multiple strings, containing the bits of your original string that were separated by commas:

```
>>> help(str.split)
Help on method_descriptor:

split(...)
    S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings

    Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
    delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
    splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
    whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
    from the result.

>>> '1,2,3'.split(',')
['1', '2', '3']
>>> '3'.split(',')
['3']
```

Now, you have a list of strings, and you want to split each of them into a list as above:

```
>>> [s.split(',') for s in ['1','2','3','22','33']]
[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['22'], ['33']]
```

Now you've got a list of lists. You want a single list containing the elements of each of the lists in your list of lists. The operation "give me each thing in each of the lists in a list of lists" maps fairly naturally to a list comprehension as follows:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
>>> [thing for alist in list_of_lists for thing in alist]
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Putting it all together:

```
>>> [bit for string in ['1','2','3','22','33'] for bit in string.split(',')]
['1', '2', '3', '22', '33']
```

So that's how you solve this with list comprehensions. There are lots of other potential solutions in other answers that are better on technical grounds. But if you're new to Python learning the entire standard library (especially powerful but abstract things like itertools) will be difficult, and don't feel like you have to. Getting comfortable with the basics will serve you more in the long run.

Comment: +1 for advising the OP on how to break down the problem into simpler sub-problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest solution I can think of.

It's using `sum()` with a generator expression, since you don't actually need to keep the sub-lists created.

```
>>> a = ['1,2,3', '22', '33']
>>> sum((s.split(',') for s in a), [])
['1', '2', '3', '22', '33']
```

Comment: This is an improper use of *sum*.  The successive concatenations what O(n**2) performance.  The code from @senderle is *much* better.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it, is:

```
>>> lst = ['1,2,3', '22', '33']
>>> res = []
>>> for x in lst:
...     res.extend(x.split(','))
>>> res
['1', '2', '3', '22', '33']
```

It doesn't use list comprehension though, but I don't see why you would use it in this case.

Comment: It also is faster then other solutions: itertools, sum, nexted listcomps

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (suppose your list is called l):

```
sum([s.split(',') for s in l], [])
```